# Image not opening in Read Write mode in Window Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using FileopenPicker to select image from PictureLibrary but after selection i m not able to open it using FileAccessMode.ReadWrite it giving me exception

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode accessmode)
```

This is my code for opening file in readwrite mode

```
StorageFile file = args.Files[0];
var stream = await file.OpenAsyn(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite); // Exception occur on this line
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
await bitmapImage.setSourceAsyc(stream);
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Maybe you need to copy the file to your app storage and open it for writing there?

Comment: I tried to copy it but it still giving me same exception of accessmode cannot be read and write, only working with read... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it in a test code, and it works for me:

```
  StorageFile newFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

  using (var stream = await newFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
  {

  }
```